# How to handle RESTful API routes to reduce returned object?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

Long story short: In a single controller, I want to manipulate returned object. Let me explain:

I have an `GET` endpoint (`/api/players`) that returns a list of objects `Player`, which looks like this:

```
[{
    "playerId": 121231231,
    "name": "M Jordan",
    "teamId": 11,
    "height": 208,
    "position": "SG",
    "field6": 13,
     ...
    "field20": 122,
}]
```

So, `Player` is an object with a lot of details. But in some cases, I need to return only list of player names. I don't need 18 additional fields. So I was thinking and have two solutions, but I'm not sure which one is better and if this is the best practice:

1. Option 1: **/api/players/names**
2. Option 2: **/api/playersNames**

I have to say I like the first one, because it's flexible. Every time I need a different "sub-object" of the player I can do it in single Controller. I can return basic object with `/api/players` and then have additional options like:

`/api/players/details`, 
`/api/players/stats`, 
`/api/players/names` etc...

What do you think? Is it a good practice? Or should I stay with ONE returned type per controller and create controllers, like: `PlayerNamesController`?

Comment: I like option 1.

Comment: Another option is to use /api/players?include=playerId,name,teamId and based on the includes and reflection, you can be very flexible

Comment: @LukasKubis thanks, but my problem with this solution is that `/api/players/` returns different type depending just on the parameter.

Comment: @AdamWojnar why do you need different types? For example if you set Player.Name, other fields remain with default value, and you can configure JSON serializer to ignore them. So you will get just JSON with "Name" property

Comment: Something else to consider, is using an OData api controller, which is available in .net core. It will allow you to return just the names, or the entire object, or whatever combination of properties you like.

Comment: @StephenByrne Thanks for the suggestions, I'm gonna take a look at this. BTW. It's not only about the json object and size of returned data. I don't want my API to compute data that will not be returned. Is in this case I have a separate query to get only player names and that's it. For "details" I need to call more queries and do more work on the API side.

Comment: @AdamWojnar - " I don't want my API to compute data that will not be returned" - sure, makes sense! And OData does that too(or at least, it used to!)...if the selection is just one field, that's all the generated statement will `SELECT` (well, apart from the entity ID)